# Strcpy Null Value Obtained From MySQL in C

Tags: mysql, c, null, strcpy, connector

I am using Connector C to connect to my MySQL database.  A modification that I have made to the database recently now allows the data in my url field to be NULL. Connector C does not appear to have any problems reading the NULL value, but when I try and pass the value to my array structure using strcpy, the program crashes. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
mysql_real_connect(conn, server,user,password,database, port, NULL, 0);
mysql_query(conn, "SELECT * FROM main WHERE propType IN ('Single Family', 'Condominium')");
res = mysql_use_result(conn);

while (((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) && (row[0] != NULL)) {

    props[count].uniqueID = atol(row[0]);
    strcpy(props[count].address, row[1]);
    .
    .
    .
    strcpy(props[count].url, row[55]);
    count++;
}
```

By tracing out output of the rows, I have determined that it is this line of code that is failing, and it is ONLY failing when row[55] is (null):

```
strcpy(props[count].url, row[55]);
```

I am fairly new to C, and I assume that the problem lies in trying to use strcpy with a null string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `strcpy` will crash if one of the pointer is `NULL`. You have to check the pointer by yourself.

Comment: What do your structure look like? What is `props[count].address`? Is it an array or a pointer? If it's a pointer, is it properly initialized?

Comment: My structure looks like the following:                                                 struct columns {
 long int uniqueID;
 char address[75];
 .
 char url[400];
};       struct columns props[200000];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is suggested above in the comment the problem is that `row[55]` has the value `NULL` and so `strcpy()` will crash. Maybe you want to try the following:

```
if (row[55] != NULL)
    strcpy(props[count].url, row[55]);
else
    props[count].url[0] = '\0';
```

Here is another example code which use a bit to store if the database contains `NULL` or a empty value:

```
if (row[55] != NULL)
{
    strcpy(props[count].url, row[55]);
    props[count].urlEmpty = false;
}
else
{
    props[count].url = '\0';          // Maybe you can skip this
    props[count].urlEmpty = true;
}
```

In this case you need to expand your structure.

Comment: I will give this a shot, but it brings up a related issue.  I have to write BACK to my database, and if my url value is NULL, I need to write back a null value to my database.  Will setting props[count].url = '\0', and then writing this value to my database set my url field to NULL in my database?  Is '\0' and NULL synonymous?

Comment: You are right '\0' and NULL is not equal. '\0' represents an empty string and NULL represents an _none exisiting string_ Then maybe you have to hold a separate bit if the value is NULL or not.

Comment: OK.  I am checking the MySQL documentation for passing a null value to a prepared statement.  Your suggestion is likely going to be very helpful, but a little over my head at the moment.  Are you suggesting that I set up a Boolean value or something?

Comment: Yes. I would expand your structure by a bool with a name like `urlEmpty` and set it to `true` if the database value is `NULL`. If you want to write it back, you can check this bit and give back either your value or `NULL`. - I have adpated my post above.

Comment: Thank you for your help Benjamin!  Between your suggestions and a little online documentation, I was able to develop a solution to handle a null string and write a null back to my database.  Unbelieveable how little documentation or tutorials exist online to help with C/MySQL interface!